# How do I pass multiple string parameters into WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to write a simple WebAPI controller to validate a userId and password. Both parameters are strings and it's a bit frustrating that this always seems to be so difficult.

The Controller code looks like:

```
[Route("api/User/{userId}, {password}"), HttpGet]
public bool IsPasswordCorrect(string userId, string password)
    {
        UserModel sm = new UserModel(userId);
        bool rtn = sm.Password == password;
        return rtn;
    }
```

The calling code looks like:

```
public bool IsPasswordValid(string userId, string password)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("IsPasswordCorrect/{userId}, {password}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("userId", userId);
        request.AddUrlSegment("password", password);
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient(Service.Location);

        var response = restClient.Execute<bool>(request);
        bool rtn = (bool)response.Data;

        return true;
    }
```

I am not able to get the calling code to access the controller code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the route as:

```
  GET {host}/api/User/{userId}, {password}
```

but looks like you are calling it as:

```
 GET {Service.Location}/IsPasswordCorrect/{userId}, {password}
```

You should call the Web API resource by the route defined in the attribute not by action name as that would result in 404.